# Webscraper breaking on google

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm learning about webscrapers and trying one of my own, but I'm running into an issue.

This webscraper gets `'http://google.com/search?q=' + mysearch`
but when I later soup.select('.r a'), I keep getting an empty list. I did some checking, and realized that the page I was going to said:

> Please click *here* if you are not redirected within a few seconds.

How can I fix this?

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("search")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--new", default=1,help="Specify the number of results to open (default: 1)")
args = parser.parse_args()


print('Googling...')

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + args.search)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,features="lxml")


linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(int(args.new), len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Thank for all your help!

Comment: Short answer: Google doesn't like to be webscraped.

Comment: Google has big money for hardware and sofware to block scripts/bots. Try different pages (with small money). See also page create to learn scraping: http://toscrape.com/